# .net core-Logging not working with modified namespace

Tags: c#, botframework

I have implemented logging in my asp.net core app but it is not logging the request & response properly if i change the namespace names from `Microsoft.BotBuilderSamples.Bots` to `OS.Bot`s ,`Microsoft.BotBuilder` to `OS.BotBuilder`

With `Microsoft.BotBuilderSamples.Bots` & `Microsoft.BotBuilder` it is working as expected but when i am changing the namespace it is not working.

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace Microsoft.BotBuilderSamples.Bots
{
    public class OasisChatBot : ActivityHandler
    {
        private IConfiguration _config;
        private ILogger<OasisChatBot> _logger;
        public OasisChatBot(IConfiguration config, ILogger<OasisChatBot> logger)
        {
            _config = config;
            _logger = logger;
        }
        protected override async Task OnMessageActivityAsync(ITurnContext<IMessageActivity> turnContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {

            var requestJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(turnContext.Activity);
           _logger.LogInformation(requestJson.ToString());
```

Comment: Logging has nothing to do with bots. Is your class called in the first place? Most likely the code that needs this class can't find it because it doesn't know anything about the new namespace

Comment: yes the class is called